# IOError: Shuffle close failed: INTERNAL: RPC error: IO error: /var/shuffle/sorted-dataset-1/1891: No space left on device

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to process ~600 xml files compressed in bz2, each file ranges from 200MB to 2GB.

I hit the error as indicated in title. I saw a question on stackoverflow that was posted two years ago. The answer points to an FAQ question which no longer exists. The answer suggests using auto scaling however I was already using it when the job failed.

Is there any other way that I can fix this?

My job id is 2019-07-14_13_04_05-9369076338245857803.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A few items to try:

Increasing the the size of the disks used by the workers using the pipeline parameter

[diskSizeGb](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-exec-params#setting-other-cloud-pipeline-options)

Another option would be to make use of the shuffle service details of which can be found here:

[Dataflow Shuffle Service](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#cloud-dataflow-shuffle)

More details about the benefits of the shuffle service can be found in this blog:

[Blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/introducing-cloud-dataflow-shuffle-for-up-to-5x-performance-improvement-in-data-analytic-pipelines)

Please make note of the price considerations of using these options at:

[Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pricing#pricing_details)